# Excel 2007 - find max value based on status criteria in data list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to find the largest value (aging days) in a set of data based on the item status.  Much like a SUMIF function, but a MAXIF (if one existed).  My data is not sorted by status.  I basically want to pull out the oldest age date per category.  I've tried several formulas I've found on the site with similar data elements, but cannot get any of them to work.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/728576/76571

Comment: Related also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274788/selecting-the-max-with-a-condition-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Type in

```
=Max(If($A$1:$A$40=A1,$B$1:$B$40))
```

and then present **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to array enter the formula. Update A1:A40 to your lookup range, A1 to your lookup value, and B1:B40 to your max range.

Comment: This is not working.  My data is on another tab, and I updated the formula to reflect that, but I keep getting a syntax error.  =Max(If('PGI_8-3-2014'!$k$2:$k$3237=A2,'PGI_8-3-2014'!$n$2:$n$3237))

Comment: Did you type the formula and copy and paste, or did you actually select the range?